# Javascript sanity check of netsuite suitescript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Currently, I have a Netsuite SuiteScript where I export saved searches to csv's. It runs but it's not reusable and I'd like to make it easier by just adding key-value pairs. I have to a lot of copy pasting and it's easy to forget to update to the latest iteration of the run. It's a scheduled search which means it runs every 15 minutes and makes it hard to debug and test.

Right now, my code looks like this, but with more searches, and it's a pain is not reusable.

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ScheduledScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/

define(['N/task'],
/**
* @param {record} record
* @param {search} search
*/

function(task) {

var FILE_ID = 2992639; 
var SEARCH_ID = 2993;

function execute(scriptContext) {
    //first search
    var searchTask1 = task.create({
        taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
    });

    searchTask1.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
    searchTask1.fileId = FILE_ID;
    var searchTaskId1 = searchTask1.submit();
    
    //next search
    FILE_ID = 2992640;
    SEARCH_ID = 3326;
    var searchTask2 = task.create({
        taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
    });

    searchTask2.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
    searchTask2.fileId = FILE_ID;
    var searchTaskId2 = searchTask2.submit();
    
        //next search
    FILE_ID = 2992634;
    SEARCH_ID = 3327;
    var searchTask3 = task.create({
        taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
    });

    searchTask3.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
    searchTask3.fileId = FILE_ID;
    var searchTaskId3 = searchTask3.submit();
    
    //this pattern repeats 19 times total. 

}

return {
    execute: execute
};
});
```

I've tried to code below

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ScheduledScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/

define(['N/task'],
/**
* @param {record} record
* @param {search} search
*/

function(task) {

    const searchList = {
        2993:2992639,
        3326:2992640,
        3327:2992634
    };

    function execute(scriptContext) {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(searchList)) {
            var searchTask = task.create({
                taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
            });

            searchTask.savedSearchId = $key;
            searchTask.fileId = $value;
            var searchTaskId = searchTask.submit();
        }
    }

    return {
        execute: execute
    };
});
```

but get the following error, and I'm not sure what is wrong with my syntax. Netsuite makes it hard to tell what I'm doing wrong, so I'm hoping someone can help here. Thanks!

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"task.submit: Missing a required argument: SearchTask.savedSearchId","stack":["createError(N/error)","execute(/SuiteScripts/dashboardreports.js:224)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"task.submit: Missing a required argument: SearchTask.savedSearchId"},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}
```

Comment: What do the `$` do with `$key` and `$value`? I’m surprised it even makes it past that point.

Comment: I took them out and tried again, no dice.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom record to store the search and file IDs, so you can add/update without modifying code.  Then I would do something like the code below.  This code first queries your custom record to get all of the search and file ids, then for each one, starts a new task.

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 * @NModuleScope Public
 */
define(['N/log', 'N/search', 'N/task'], function(log, search, task) {
    function execute(context) {
        var searchInfos = getSearchInfo();

        searchInfos.forEach(function(searchInfo) {
            var searchTask = task.create({
                taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
            });

            searchTask.savedSearchId = searchInfo.searchId;
            searchTask.fileId = searchInfo.fileId;

            var searchTaskId = searchTask.submit();
            log.debug({ title: 'searchTaskId', details: searchTaskId });
        });
    }

    function getSearchInfo() {
        var results = search.create({
            type: 'customrecord_search_to_csv_info',
            filters: [
                ['isinactive', 'is', 'F']
            ],
            columns: [
                'custcolumn_search_id',
                'custcolumn_file_id'
            ]
        }).run().getRange({ start: 0, end: 1000 });

        return (results || []).map(function(result) {
            return {
                searchId: result.getValue({ name: 'custcolumn_search_id '}),
                fileId: result.getValue({ name: 'custcolumn_file_id' })
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        execute: execute
    };
});
```