# Netsuite suitescript for converting saved search to csv

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to export simple script to csv with code below in suitescript 2.0 ,

```
require(['N/task'],
function(task) {
    
 var SEARCH_ID = 1487;



       var searchTask = task.create({

           taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH

     });

       searchTask.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;

       var path = 'Test/export.csv';
 
       searchTask.filepath = path;
       
       var searchTaskId = searchTask.submit();
 
       var a = 0;});
```

However, it gives the following error,

> SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT 10/5/2021 10:15:40.917
> {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"task.submit:
> Missing a required argument: fileId /
> filePath","stack":["createError(N/error.js)","(adhoc−1debugger.user:25)","(adhoc−1debugger.user:3)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"task.submit:
> Missing a required argument: fileId /
> filePath"},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}

Please guide me how to troubleshoot it. I have never worked with script before so any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question, might be helpful  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69213113/javascript-sanity-check-of-netsuite-suitescript ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I did modify the code referring that link. It executes without error, but there is another problem now. It does not save anything to file

Answer (score 0):

The filePath needs to be a full path from the top of your File Cabinet hierarchy. All the folders referenced must exist.

Additionally the recommended way to create the search task is as a single step:

```
var searchTask = task.create({
    taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH,
    savedSearchId: searchId,
    filePath: filePath
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of file path I gave file ID but no errors and no csv file is created in  file folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).